# What exactly must be specified for keycode and keychar when simulating keypresses (vb.net or c# with dotnetbrowser)

Tags: c#, vb.net, keypress, dotnetbrowser

(I'm asking with vb examples, but the same applies for c# and the answer would be the same.)

I'm trying to fill in a form using dotnetbrowser and have problems understanding what exactly to put into the keychar and keycode/virtualkey parameters when I want to "press" special keys like "down arrow", "tab", "enter". The "[KeyCode Enumeration](https://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/apidoc/2.1.1/html/T_DotNetBrowser_Input_Keyboard_Events_KeyCode.htm)" table lists, for example, "tab (9)", return (13)", "down arrow (40)", "A (65)". So, to type an A I would need to do the following:

```
SimulateKey(keyboard, 65, "A")
```

or, just written differently,

```
SimulateKey(keyboard, 65, chr(65))
```

whichs works fine for "A", and

```
SimulateKey(keyboard, 97, chr(97))
```

works fine for "a", although I don't understand why, because 97 is the keycode for "Numpad1".

But what do I specify for keychar for the special characters when I want to type tab-return-down-A?

```
SimulateKey(keyboard, 9, chr(9))
SimulateKey(keyboard, 13, chr(13))
SimulateKey(keyboard, 40, chr(40))   'where chr(40) is actually an opening parantheses "("
SimulateKey(keyboard, 65, chr(65))
```

or is keychar empty or space for the special characters like

```
SimulateKey(keyboard, 9, "") 'nothing between the qoutes
SimulateKey(keyboard, 13, " ") 'space-character (asc 32) between the quotes
```

What would I need to speciafy when I actually want to type an open parantheses "(", which is asc 40 - and thus has the same code as down? I would appreciate a thourough explanation on the keycode and keychar values.

For completeness, this is the code I use for SimulateKey (from the [vb dotnetbrowser example](https://github.com/TeamDev-IP/DotNetBrowser-Examples/blob/master/vbnet/KeyboardEventSimulation.Wpf/MainWindow.xaml.vb) or [here for c#](https://github.com/TeamDev-IP/DotNetBrowser-Examples/blob/master/csharp/KeyboardEventSimulation.WinForms/Form1.cs))

```
Private Shared Sub SimulateKey(keyboard As IKeyboard, key As KeyCode, keyChar As String, Optional ByVal modifiers As KeyModifiers = Nothing)
    modifiers = If(modifiers, New KeyModifiers())
    Dim keyPressedEventArgs = New KeyPressedEventArgs With {
            .KeyChar = keyChar,
            .VirtualKey = key,
            .Modifiers = modifiers
            }

    Dim keyTypedEventArgs = New KeyTypedEventArgs With {
            .KeyChar = keyChar,
            .VirtualKey = key,
            .Modifiers = modifiers
            }
    Dim keyReleasedEventArgs = New KeyReleasedEventArgs With {
            .VirtualKey = key,
            .Modifiers = modifiers
            }

    keyboard.KeyPressed.Raise(keyPressedEventArgs)
    keyboard.KeyTyped.Raise(keyTypedEventArgs)
    keyboard.KeyReleased.Raise(keyReleasedEventArgs)
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it WPF? Does it have to be?

Comment: No, it's WinForms. This is also - I think - pretty much a general question, because the mechanism as such appears to be generic and not even directly linked to dotnetbrowser, although my use-case and the code I showed uses dotnetbrowser.

Comment: Seem like hard work when SendKeys is a thing

Comment: @Caius Jard: There is a significant difference: SendKeys actually acts as a real, system-wide keyboard and sends the keys to whatever app currently has the focus. This will cause the entire system to fail once the user clicks in some other window while the keys are sent. With the SimulateKey-method I can send the keys to a certain browser-control in my app, even if it runs in the background and doesn't have the focus. (This is why there is a keyboard-object, which is defined elsewhere in the program and is linked to the browser control of my app.)

Answer (score 0):

The key codes are Windows virtual key codes, which are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes).

These codes represent physical keys on the keyboard, not characters. To distinguish between two characters that use the same key (such as <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd>, or <kbd>(</kbd> and <kbd>9</kbd>), you will need additional information, such as whether the shift key was down and/or caps lock was on at the time the key was pressed. In fact, this is how `KeyChar` is computed from the key code for a real keyboard event. On the other hand, `KeyChar` cannot distinguish a regular digit key from a numpad digit key, and some keys (such as function keys) do not have any associated character, so the only way to detect these keys is through the key code.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Now the question remains what keycode/keychar pairs I need to specify for {Down} and special characters like 'ö' or 'ß' that have no apparent keycode. Also, I wonder why keycode 97/keychar "a" really produced an "a" and 65/"A" produced an "A". This is what I wanted, be for "A" shouldn't I need to specificy that the shift-modifier goes along with it?

Comment: ('ö', by the way, is on the German keyboard to the right of the "L"-key, where, on US layouts, the semicolon resides and 'ß' is the key to the right of the digit "0" or two keys to the left of backspace.)

Comment: The keycode for the semicolon (or ö in the German layout) is VK_OEM_1 (186), as mentioned in the keycode list. You don't have to specify shift modifiers if you are constructing a *synthetic* keyboard event, just specify {keycode = 65, keychar = 65} for 'A' and {keycode = 65, keychar = 97} for 'a', for instance. The shift and/or caps lock state is what is used by the UI framework (e.g. Windows Forms or WPF) to compute the KeyChar for a *real* keyboard event received from the operating system.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but... First: What keychar would I need to specify for keycode 40 (down arrow)? Second: Assume I wanted to "type" normal text with foreign characters, some - like the accented á, ô, etc. that you normally get by typing the accent key followed by the letter - appear very difficult to encode. That would be a very long case-block to handle all the possible characters and upper-/lowercase-variations. Isn't there a simple way to translate the characters of the text "André Müller-Schößler" into keycodes and keychars? I can't believe I have to invent the wheel here...

Comment: @Thomas If you want to get the exact keycode/keychar values for all possible keys and key combinations (e.g. accent + letter), you should write a test app in whatever UI framework you are using that listens to keyboard events and writes the values somewhere, such the console or a text box.